# "UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]" for Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, landscape, landscape-portrait

I have to ask it. Using

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]
```

Is a beautiful way to get the working area of the iphone or ipad in portrait mode. But, if I want get the same size in landscape, there are other code, or I will have to create:

```
CGRect landscape = CGRectMake(0, 20, 1024, 748)
```

This is even not generic for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: I wonder if it's safe to presume that the applicationFrame selector will always return the area in portrait mode. (And to just switch the values manually.)

Comment: Did you resolve this successfully? Transposing the width & height values is undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] frame]`

Comment: When I call this during my view controller's loadView selector, I get a CGRect with both origin and size set to (0, 0).

Comment: I'm not really sure but it worked for me: `loadView] [Line: 788] [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] frame]: {{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}`. Can you try calling `[super loadView]` first? If that didn't work then I suggest try using another method. `sizeToFit` perhaps?